# Installing Aptana Studio 3 on Eclipse 4.2

Tags: eclipse, aptana

using eclipse 4.2 and I'm trying to install Aptana Studio 3 on it.. When I do I get this error log

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.4.0.201304151542-7E7G-7MEMVKUHgFcLgFbkKoz0t-7 (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.4.0.201304151542-7E7G-7MEMVKUHgFcLgFbkKoz0t-7)
  Software currently installed: PyDev for Eclipse 2.7.5.2013052819 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.5.2013052819)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Core Plug-in 1.5.5.2010030420 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.5.2010030420)
Core Plug-in 2.3.0.2011121518 (org.python.pydev.core 2.3.0.2011121518)
Core Plug-in 1.6.1.2010080312 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.1.2010080312)
Core Plug-in 2.2.2.2011082312 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.2.2011082312)
Core Plug-in 1.5.1.1258496115 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.1.1258496115)
Core Plug-in 2.7.5.2013052819 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.5.2013052819)
Core Plug-in 2.7.1.2012100913 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.1.2012100913)
Core Plug-in 2.2.4.2011110216 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.4.2011110216)
Core Plug-in 1.6.3.2010100513 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.3.2010100513)
Core Plug-in 2.2.3.2011100616 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.3.2011100616)
Core Plug-in 2.6.0.2012062818 (org.python.pydev.core 2.6.0.2012062818)
Core Plug-in 2.2.1.2011071313 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.1.2011071313)
Core Plug-in 2.1.0.2011052613 (org.python.pydev.core 2.1.0.2011052613)
Core Plug-in 2.7.3.2013031601 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.3.2013031601)
Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090711 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090711)
Core Plug-in 1.5.7.2010050621 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.7.2010050621)
Core Plug-in 1.5.2.1260362205 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.2.1260362205)
Core Plug-in 2.0.0.2011040403 (org.python.pydev.core 2.0.0.2011040403)
Core Plug-in 2.7.4.2013051601 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.4.2013051601)
Core Plug-in 1.5.8.2010062823 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.8.2010062823)
Core Plug-in 1.5.0.1251989166 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.0.1251989166)
Core Plug-in 2.7.0.2012100419 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.0.2012100419)
Core Plug-in 1.6.0.2010071813 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.0.2010071813)
Core Plug-in 1.6.4.2011010200 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.4.2011010200)
Core Plug-in 2.5.0.2012040618 (org.python.pydev.core 2.5.0.2012040618)
Core Plug-in 1.5.6.2010033101 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.6.2010033101)
Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063001 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063001)
Core Plug-in 1.5.9.2010063000 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.9.2010063000)
Core Plug-in 1.6.5.2011020317 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.5.2011020317)
Core Plug-in 1.6.2.2010090812 (org.python.pydev.core 1.6.2.2010090812)
Core Plug-in 2.7.2.2013031501 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.2.2013031501)
Core Plug-in 2.2.0.2011062419 (org.python.pydev.core 2.2.0.2011062419)
Core Plug-in 2.7.0.2013032300 (org.python.pydev.core 2.7.0.2013032300)
Core Plug-in 1.5.4.2010011921 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.4.2010011921)
Core Plug-in 2.4.0.2012020116 (org.python.pydev.core 2.4.0.2012020116)
Core Plug-in 1.5.3.1260479439 (org.python.pydev.core 1.5.3.1260479439)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.4.0.201304151542-7E7G-7MEMVKUHgFcLgFbkKoz0t-7 (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.4.0.201304151542-7E7G-7MEMVKUHgFcLgFbkKoz0t-7)
To: com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group [2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Aptana Pydev 2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee (com.aptana.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.0.2013032300-7g9I-8Jez0cfdJcee)
To: org.python.pydev.core [2.7.0.2013032300]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: PyDev for Eclipse 2.7.5.2013052819 (org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group 2.7.5.2013052819)
To: org.python.pydev.core [2.7.5.2013052819]
```

I seem to have some sort of dependency conflict..
any ideas on what can be done?

The Eclipse used is a fresh install with updated ADT and PyDev Plugins

Comment: I would try uninstalling your PvDev plugin and then reinstall it after Aptana if Aptana's PyDev stuff doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This error message says your PyDev 2.7.5 needs a higher version of the pydev core than aptana 2.7.0.  You need a version of Aptana that's blessed for Juno that includes PyDev, or you need to install Aptana into a package of Juno that doesn't include PyDev.